# Error: xctool not found. Please install it and bootstrap again

Tags: xcode

when i write this command in my terminal
script/bootstrap
this error poped to me
Error: xctool not found. Please install it and bootstrap again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just open your terminal and install XCTool

```
brew install xctool
```

Comment: This presumes that the user knows what homebrew is and has it installed

Comment: If user run brew command then got another error he will search for it